# Chatbot Testing with Botium

Tags: testing, automation, chatbot

"I am working on an application having chatbot which user can use after log into the application and I am trying to test this chat bot using Botium API, but I am unable to do the same.

Could anyone please tell me:

1. Does Botium support testing of the user authenticated chatbots??
2. If Botium supports user authenticated chatbot,could anyone please guide me to perform the test of the same?"

Comment: Please more details - what kind of chatbot is it ? what technology ?